# dplyr: Replace NAs and 0s with conditional subgroup means

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to replace all NAs and 0s in a large dataset with their respective group mean -- computed on the basis of cases that are not NA or 0.

```
Source: local data frame [174,019 x 3]
Groups: name

   student   name  hours
1       s1    ABC    1.0
2       s1    DEF     NA
3       s2    DEF    0.5
4       s3     NA    2.0
5       s3    ABC    2.0
6       s4    GHI      0
```

This solution using `dplyr` works as intended, but can this be done in one chain?

```
avg <- workshops %>%
  filter(hours > 0 & !is.na(name)) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarize(avg.hours = mean(hours, na.rm = TRUE))

workshops <- workshops %>%
  left_join(avg, by = "name") %>%
  mutate(hours = if_else(hours > 0, hours, avg.hours, avg.hours)) %>%
  select(-avg.hours)
```

**Updated solution**

```
workshop <- workshop %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(hours = ifelse(!is.na(name), replace(hours, hours == 0 | is.na(hours),
                 mean(`is.na<-`(hours, hours == 0), na.rm = TRUE)), NA))
```

Comment: From what I understand you just want to treat `0` as `NA`. The best would be to make this intention clear by using `na_if` first, and then just do a grouped `mutate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
workshop%>%
  group_by(name)%>%
  mutate(hours=replace(hours,hours==0|is.na(hours),
                 mean(`is.na<-`(hours,hours==0),na.rm = T)))
```

Comment: Wasn't familiar with the `is.na<-` function. Neat! However, this also imputes the mean for all rows with `name` missing. I included an updated version in the question.

Comment: Clever use of `is.na<-`. It a worth including some sample data to make it easier for future users.

Comment: @mnml if you do not need those rows, just filter them out. ie `filter(is.na(name))`

Comment: @MKR there was no data to work with. I just followed the logic

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option with `na.aggregate` from `zoo`. After grouping by 'name', change the 0's to NA with `na_if` and apply `na.aggregate` to replace the missing values with the `mean` (by default, the `FUN` parameter is `mean`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
workshops %>%
    group_by(name) %>% 
    mutate(hours = na.aggregate(na_if(hours, 0)))
```

#### data

```
workshops <- structure(list(student = c("s1", "s1", "s2", "s3", "s3", 
 "s4"), name = c("ABC", "DEF", "DEF", NA, "ABC", "GHI"),
 hours = c(1, NA, 0.5, 2, 2, 0)), .Names = c("student", "name", "hours"), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```